# Path.Combine() does not add directory separator after drive letter

Tags: c#, .net, path

Am I using the `Path.Combine` Method Incorrectly?
I Get This Result With `Path.Combine(string[])`:

```
C:Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\TestProject\\Connections.xml
```

And This is the desired Result of the less desirable code:the one that is the result generated by the commented out code):

```
C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\TestProject\\Connections.xml
```

Note the missing `\\` after the drive letter in the first path.

The old method (manually adding backslashes, commented out) works well, but I'm pretty sure that it wouldn't work under Linux or something else if compiled with mono.

```
string[] TempSave = Application.UserAppDataPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string[] DesiredPath = new string[TempSave.Length - 2];
for (int i = 0; i < TempSave.Length - 2; i++)
{
    //SaveLocation += TempSave[i] + "\\";//This Works
    DesiredPath[i] = TempSave[i];
}
SaveLocation = Path.Combine(DesiredPath);//This Doesn't Work.    
ConnectionsFs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(SaveLocation,FileName)/*SaveLocation+FileName*/, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

Basically, I want the end Result to be the `TestProject` Directory, not the project itself or its version.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find the grandparent folder of the `UserAppDataPath` folder. Why not just combine with `"..\.."` instead? That is: `Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, @"..\..")`