# Why Directory.GetFiles() doesn't accept the input of the variable?

Tags: c#, filesystems

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace GetFilesFromDirectory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write your Name of Disc");
            string myDisc = Console.ReadLine();
            string myDisc1 = "@\"";
            Console.WriteLine("Write your Directory");
            string myDir1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string myDir = ":\\";
            string myDir2 = "\\\"";
            string myPath = myDisc1 + myDisc + myDir + myDir1 + myDir2;
            Console.WriteLine(myPath);
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(myPath);


            foreach (var files in filePaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(files);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably making the wrong path, debug and see what you have in myPath before you call GetFiles. This myPath values should open the given folder

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you get compiler errors? Logical errors? What did you expect to happen, what *does* happen?

Comment: Show at least an example of contents of `myPath`

Comment: Use `Path.Combine()` in your code. They invented it for these cases.

Comment: The compiler fails to compile. It does not like some signs that I use to complete the path in myPath variable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell your `myPath` will look like `@"discName:\dirName\"`, you don't need to append the `@"` or `"`.

These symbols are used when you are creating a new string variable to note that is a [String literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but you are including these characters in the actual string you are generating.

In other words, remove `myDisc1` and `myDir2`

Better than that, as noted by DrKoch

```
 string myPath = Path.Combine(myDisc + @":\", myDir1);
```

Comment: Actually you need to add ":\\" after myDisc

Comment: The slash won't be added if the path is a drive reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909008/path-combine-does-not-add-directory-separator-after-drive-letter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write your Name of Disc");
        //You need to add :\ to make it a fullPath
        string myDisc = Console.ReadLine()+":\\";

        Console.WriteLine("Write your Directory");
        string myDir1 = Console.ReadLine();


        string myPath =  Path.Combine(myDisc , myDir1);
        Console.WriteLine(myPath);
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(myPath);


        foreach (var files in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(files);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

What are you doing is creating a string wich is the literal reprentation of the string you want but you don't need to do this.
For example if you write this:
`string path=@"c:\dir\subdir";` its real value will be `c:\dir\subdir` 
instead this `"@\"c:\\dir\\subdir\""`; will be
`@"c:\dir\subdir"` 
Read these articles to better understand string literals and verbatim strings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx